# Edit a docx with open xml

Tags: c#

I am trying to edit a word document, with open xml, but I don't have a satisfying result :

Here is the raw document :

[image]

Here, I just got a sentence to start the document. and after the `:` I must add several lines.

The result I want is something like this(for some reasons, I had to erase some datas on the screens, but this does not affect the question) :

[image]

But I only got a result like this :

[image]

So, in the third image, the text is not center and also does not have any tab.
Plus, is is not in bold (if is is not underline, that is not a problem).

But the real problem is the fact that it is left align, with no tabs, while it should be center align with tabs.

Here is the code I have :

```
                                    Text text = sdtFils.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
                                    string[] lst = variableCourrier.Tables[0].Rows[0][v_ligne["NOM_CHAMP"].ToString()].ToString().Split("$".ToCharArray());
                                    Paragraph existPar = sdtFils.Descendants<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (existPar == null)
                                    {
                                        existPar = sdtFils.Ancestors<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
                                    }
                                    Run existRun = sdtFils.Descendants<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
                                    foreach (string str in lst)
                                    {
                                        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                                        
                                        ParagraphProperties pPr = new ParagraphProperties(new Tabs(new TabStop() { Val = TabStopValues.Center, Position = 7372 }),
                                            new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Left },
                                            new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Paragraphedeliste" },
                                            new Indentation() { Start = (int.Parse(existPar.ParagraphProperties.Indentation.Left.Value) + int.Parse(existPar.ParagraphProperties.Indentation.FirstLine.Value)).ToString() });
                                        
                                        string[] lstDetails = str.Split(";".ToCharArray());
                                        int j = 0;
                                        foreach (string strDetail in lstDetails)
                                        {
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strDetail))
                                            {
                                                TabChar tab = new TabChar();
                                                Text t = new Text();
                                                Run r = new Run();
                                                RunProperties runPr = new RunProperties(new FontSize() { Val = existRun.RunProperties.FontSize.Val });

                                                r.AppendChild(runPr);
                                                t.Text = j == 0 ? "" + strDetail : " " + strDetail;
                                                r.AppendChild(t);


                                                if (j != lstDetails.Length - 1)
                                                {
                                                    Break br = new Break();
                                                    r.AppendChild(br);
                                                }
                                                p.AppendChild(r);
                                                j++;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        text.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(p);
                                    }
```

With this code, I split each part of a string, so that I can put them into their lines.

I think the part that is not correct, is when I define the `Paragraph` element, but I don't see how to correct it, to obtain a reuslt that will look like the second image.

Anybody can help me with this?

If it is not clear enough, please tell me, I will edit the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool** (remember a .docx file is a collection of XML documents zipped into a single file), open your *.docx and click **Reflect code** to see the code needed to style the document properly.

[image]

Also you can use [**Open XML Package Editor for Visual Studio**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b) add-in that provides an easy way to parse and edit Open Packaging Conventions files, including Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Visio documents.

Everything is [open source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-Sdk) and available on Github.